# request every 5 min in a loop Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, strava

I need to make a get calls request to an external server in a loop but the problem is that calling all in the loop can cause rate limits so I just wanna make the calls inside the loop every 5 min or 10 or so , is there a way that can help achieve this.
here is my code :

```
    const util = require('util');

const StravaClientService = require("../../strava/client.service");
const StravaActivityService = require("../../strava/activity.service");
const _ = require("underscore");
const fs = require("fs");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const ids = require("underscore");
const data = require("underscore");


AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1",
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports = (router) => {
    router.get("/streams/:id", async (req, res, done) => {
        const userc = req.user;
        const access_token = userc.access_token;

   const ids = [4401422821,
       4401416494,
       4401413107,

       ]
        const stravaClient = StravaClientService.getClient(access_token);
        const activityService = StravaActivityService(stravaClient);
        //
         var params = {
            TableName:"run-id",
             Key: {
                 "id": userc.stravaId,
            }

         };





        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success", data.Item.json);
                ids.map(( id ) =>  setTimeout(activityService.streamActivity,5000,id))//data.Item.json

            }
        });
```

Comment: is this a lambda function?

Comment: no, i am just using dynamodb

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `setInterval` is enough in your scenario. However, you could try to use [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) which helps to manage your cron jobs.

Comment: do you know how I can use this to queue requests rather than using set timeout ?

Comment: Just given a crontab expression looks like */5 * * * * as it's one of option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval`

```js
setInterval(() => {
  ids.map(( id ) =>  setTimeout(activityService.streamActivity,5000,id))
}, 5000); \\ for 5 minutes
```

Comment: the problem here is that is doesnt run each iteration after  5 min  ,instead it run all the loop after the interval

Comment: You mean to run the `map` function every 5 min, right?

Comment: yes i want to get each map iteration after 5 minute not in one time (like in a loop i want to run each iteration after 5 minute ) if you know what i mean

Comment: So why don't you put the `map` into a `setInterval`'s callback?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, does it solve your problem?

Comment: thank you so much but it didn't work as i wanted exactly , but lune's answer did the trick using index offset.

Answer (score 0):

Use the index to offset?

```
ids.map(( id, index ) =>  setInterval(()=>activityService.streamActivity(id),(5+index) * 60000))//data.Item.json
```